# ReactJS .NET not able to set cookie

Tags: .net, reactjs, cookies, cross-domain, setcookie

I have a .NET5 API with CORS Allowed and a react app that uses axios to make requests to the API.
I want to set an HTTPOnly Cookie in my controller, but `Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions)` is not working for some reason, when i go into Chrome "Application" tab, my cookie is not present.

My code in **Controller** looks like this:

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
    IsEssential = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
};
Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);
```

My **Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyCorsPolicy,
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr"), b =>
            b.MigrationsAssembly("Template_Data")));

        var appSettingsConfig = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsConfig);

        services.AddScoped<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();

        // For Identity  
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudience = Configuration["AppSettings:JWT:ValidAudience"],
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["AppSettings:JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AppSettings:JWT:SecretKey"])),
            // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

        // Adding Authentication  
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        });

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ASP.NET 5 Web API v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(MyCorsPolicy);

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by adding `.AllowCredentials()` in my **Startup.cs** like this:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyCorsPolicy,
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

And in my react app i added `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;` in the file where i import and setup axios.